# ¿ por que se pega la ventana cuando presiono el botón?

Tags: python, tkinter

el problema que tengo es que cada vez que presiono el botón primero se queda hundido(presionado) y la ventana no responde no se a que se debe esto.

sospecho a que se debe a los multiprocesos, investigue un poco pero no entiendo como implementarlo al código.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x250")

def texto_a_voz(texto):
   """
   Esta funcion nos permite pasar un texto(string) a voz
   :param texto:
   :return:
   """
   engine = pyttsx3.init()
   engine.setProperty("rate", 130)
   voces = engine.getProperty("voices")
   engine.setProperty("voice", voces[0].id)

   engine.say(texto)
   engine.runAndWait()


def reconocimiento_de_voz():
   r = sr.Recognizer()

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       audio = r.listen(source)

       try:
           texto = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
           print(texto)
           return texto
       except:
           pass

Button(root, text="Click", command=reconocimiento_de_voz).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Revisa la tabulación del código porque, si no recuerdo mal, tras un with, se debe tabular todo lo que esté empleando el `as` del with y tu `audio = r.listen(source)` no está bien tabulado.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez nop, no es eso, yo creo que tiene que ver con algo de los hilos o multiprocesos algo que permita ejecutar dos cosas a la vez de manera paralela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione tuve que crear otra función(worker) y en esa función hacer un thread luego le paso la función worker al botón y funciona bien.

```
def reconocimiento_de_voz():
   r = sr.Recognizer()

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       audio = r.listen(source)

       try:
           texto = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
           print(texto)
           return texto
       except:
           pass 

def t():
    valor = reconocimiento_de_voz()
    print(valor)


def worker():
    p = threading.Thread(target=t)
    p.start()
    p.is_alive()
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto soluciono mi pregunta, pero ahora me genero una nueva pregunta, ¿ como puedo obtener el valor retornado de la función ? por que si imprimo el valor de la variable p me imprime el thread y necesito el valor que me devuelve la función de reconocimiento de voz

```
def reconocimiento_de_voz():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            texto = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
            print(texto)
            return texto
        except:
            pass        

def t():
    p = threading.Thread(target=reconocimiento_de_voz)
    p.start()
    p.is_alive()
```

Comment: en efecto, la variable p corresponde al thread, si quieres imprimir el valor que te retorna la función reconociemnto_de_voz tienes que declarar una variable global y después reasignarla dentro la función target del thread con el valor que retorna. Así, el valor estará disponible en cualquier parte que la mandes llamar. También recuerda finalizar el thread cuando termines el programa con el método join()

Comment: En vez de una variable global, podría usar un callback. Python permite el paso de funciones como parámetros así que puede simplemente pasar la función que necesita que se ejecute al terminar como parámetro a un thread propio

Comment: @EdherCarbajal es necesario finalizar el thread ? lo que pasa es que si le paso el metodo join la aplicacion se vuelve a pegar

Comment: Te recomiendo hacerlo. Para evitar que se quede congelado puedes cerrar el thread una vez que cierres explícitamente la ventana principal de tkinter o cuando finalices todo el proceso de la función Target. Si no lo finalizas se puede buggear y cuando cierras todo sigue el proceso